# apex class to delete records older than 90 days

Tags: apex, bulk-delete

Calling an apex action to delete records older than 90 days. I'm wondering if the code I have is the best practice or is there a better/ more structured way to write this:

```
public class DeleteOldInteractions
{
    @InvocableMethod
    public static void InteractionDelete(List<Id> interactionIds)
        {
        List<Interaction__c> interactions =[select id from Interaction__c
                          WHERE Interaction_Source__c = 'Student Information System' AND CreatedDate != LAST_N_DAYS:90];
        delete interactions;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code seems fine to me.

You don't need to explicitly assign the query result, however; you can give it directly to the DML operation:

```
    delete [select id from Interaction__c
                      WHERE Interaction_Source__c = 'Student Information System' AND CreatedDate != LAST_N_DAYS:90];
```

Note that you are vulnerable to limits issues if the data volume in this object (and which is responsive to the query) approaches 10,000 records, or there is other high-volume DML taking place in the transaction.

Comment: Thank you for your advice sir. much appreciated